# Home/Index page scrolls down by itself while debugging in Visual Studio 2015 Community using Browser Link

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, model-view-controller, browser-link

Has someone seen something like this recently? I created an MVC project and used the default screens to replicate the problem.

I tried to debug the project using the Browser Link on Chrome, Edge and Firefox and all of them scroll down the Index.cshtml by itself.

The same problem occurs in another laptop.

I tried using Visual Studio 2013 Professional, and this problem is NOT showing up.

Please see the images of the default Index.cshtml with more bootstrap rows to simulate a long page, and a snapshot of the resulting page that scrolls down my itself

Thanks for any help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3kXa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPiyJ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem on VS15 enterprise.. 
what worked for me is disabling 'Browser Link' 
[image]

Comment: It works also for be but I'd like to know why this new strange behaviour

Comment: I tried to test this scenario on VS 2017 Community Edition and this problem is NOT showing up. For me, I think it's adios to VS 2015 and hola to 2017!

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the Web Accessibility Checker Extension. Version 1.4.47 has fixed this issue.